# jstl - how do i pass an expression language variable to a javascript alert?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, el

I'm trying to make an admin page connected to a servlet, where I can insert some elements into a database. It's a demo of a concert ticket booking website and I use a form to input data, and the servlet to validate it.

If the servlet finds invalid data in one or more of the form's fields, it returns a custom message as a formatted string named mismatchOut - one invalidity message per line, e.g.:

```
Concert date must be in yyyy-mm-dd format!
start time must be in hh:mm:ss format!
```

I pass this in my jsp as:

```
<c:set var="invalidConcertInputMessage" value="${mismatchOut}" scope="page" />
```

What I want to do is pass this message to an alert, which will show the message to the admin user.

I've tried:

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        alert("${invalidConcertInputMessage}");
    </script>
</c:if>
```

,

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        alert(${invalidConcertInputMessage});
    </script>
</c:if>
```

,

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        alert(<c:out value="${invalidConcertInputMessage}");
    </script>
</c:if>
```

,

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        alert("<c:out value="${invalidConcertInputMessage}" />");
    </script>
</c:if>
```

and:

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        alert('<c:out value="${invalidConcertInputMessage}" />');
    </script>
</c:if>
```

and nothing seems to work. I'm probably missing the sintax here, as I'm a total newbie when it comes tu UI.

This works and prints out an alert saying "some text":

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        alert("some text");
    </script>
</c:if>
```

Please tell me how I can pass my custom message to the alert. Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

It seems the problem was that I was posting newline characters to my custom message string as `\n`, but java parsed them as its own newlines, instead of just sending `\n` to java script, which resulted in some form of invalid string that it wouldn't parse.

I fixed the problem by replacing `\n with`\n` in the custom string sent by the servlet.

And for anyone else in this predicament, this is the syntax that I got it working with:

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidConcertInputMessage}">
    <script>
        var message = "${invalidConcertInputMessage}";
        alert(message);
    </script>
</c:if>
```